# ´Discord Bot download Youtube Videos Python

Tags: python, discord.py

Hi im creating a Discord Bot which can download Youtube Videos and should send the video to t6he discord server.
It downloads the Video but cant send it to the server

This is my code:

```
from pytube import YouTube
import discord
import os
import random
import time
from discord.ext import commands

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("We have logged in as {0.user}".format(client))

@client.event

async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  if message.content.startswith("/download"):
    await message.channel.send("Please Type the Link")
    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
      if message.author == client.user:
        return
      link = message.content
      video = YouTube(link)
      stream = video.streams.get_highest_resolution()
      stream.download()
      with open(stream.download, 'rb') as f:
        picture = discord.File(f)
        await message.channel.send(file=discord.File(stream.download))

client.run("TOKEN")
```

And this is my error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File"opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
        await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "main.py", line 30,, in on_message
    with open(stream.download, 'rb') as f:
TypeError: expect str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not method
```

Comment: and whats your problem / error?

Comment: Maybe not post your token on the internet. Please revoke this specific token and create a new one.

Comment: yes @Kraay89 is right, Please revoke the token its not secure to share it on the internet. Also it might be a problem with the size limit discord has for different file types. Perhaps you should check the size of your video file and if it is not within the limits, that might be the reason for your error. And an error traceback in the post will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: This is my error: Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File"opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
  await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "main.py", line 30,, in on_message
 with open(stream.download, 'rb') as f:
TypeError: expect str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not method

and it didnt send the Video

Comment: Hey @TheNewRock1909, I suggest you mention the error also in the post as well, since that makes it easier for future visitors to read it all in one go.

Comment: Thanks for updating your post with the error traceback info @TheNewRock1909

Comment: I think i got it all you need to do is replace this line -: `with open(stream.download, 'rb') as f:` with this -: `with open(stream.download(), 'rb') as f:` Since the [download](https://pytube.io/en/latest/api.html#pytube.Stream.download) method is returning the path to the saved stream, but before you were passing the method reference and not the path, to get the return value you need to call the function using `()`.

Comment: Stream.download is a function  which you call in the line above.

Comment: Yes @2e0byo, I had understood it wrong. I got it now. Thanks! :)

Comment: @MatrixProgrammer yes the files are to big for discord

Comment: If the size is bigger than allowed, even if this error is fixed, I am afraid it might not work.

Comment: But the fix to this error is as mentioned above by me, check [this](https://pytube.io/en/latest/api.html#pytube.Stream.download) out for more information.

Comment: replace `stream.download` with `stream.download()`. `stream.download` is a reference to the download method of stream object, but in your case you want the returned value of the method for which you need to call it like so -: `stream.download()`.

Comment: No problem! @TheNewRock1909 :)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the output *file name*, which you can get from your previous call to download.  Currently you are passing a *function*, hence the error.  I would do something like this:

```
from tempfile import Temporary Directory

...
with TemporaryDirectory() as d:
    fn = stream.download(output_path=d)
    with open(fn, 'rb') as f:
        ...
```

When you leave the `with TemporaryDirectory` block the output directory will be deleted, which is probably what you want as it prevents your disk being  filled up with videos after you've uploaded them.

Note that I only call the download method *once* to avoid redownloading the video.

Do note that if the file you are trying to upload is larger than the size limit the server will accept (here: discord) any number if things can happen.  A well written server will error early when it gets the header, and that error will likely propagate back to your application.  Some servers will abruptly drop the connection when they hit the size limit, throwing a connection error your end which can be hard to debug.  Still others will fail silently, or truncate the file at their end, leaving you wondering what happened.  I expect discord servers are well written, so expect errors.

Comment: @MatrixProgrammer a comment which suggest *two* calls to the same download function (by not mentioning deleting the previous line, because it's a comment), and the policy here is *not to answer in comments*.  Either the question should be closed as 'caused by typos', or it should be answered.  I'm very happy to delete this answer if you want to post one: as soon as the error was posted the problem was obvious and I started writing *before* I saw your comment.  Rather than have a three line answer I mentioned cleaning up files with a tempdir, which is probably worth thinking about

Comment: Yes, and I by no means wanted to disrespect you, or the points you mentioned in your answer. I am still learning and thanks for informing me about this policy, my bad! I will keep it in mind from next time onwards. I am sorry if it felt disrespectful in anyway to you. Thanks

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149699/a-method-for-the-op-to-accept-comments for the problems with unanswered questions.  But as I said I *didn't* see your comment till I'd started writing, and if you want to post an answer (avoiding duplicate calls to download()) I'll happily delete this one in it's favour (if nothing has happened to it) :)

Comment: Thanks for the link @2e0byo, I will definitely check this out and be careful next time around.

Comment: Also I think you should also mention about the size problem with discord for future visitors, in your answer, just a suggestion. Thanks! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238384/discussion-between-2e0byo-and-matrix-programmer).